# How to play sounds and music in java without lag

Tags: java, audio

I wrote this audio class that is used by my soundplayer class it works correctly with no errors but causes my game to hiccup or jerk when the sound is used in quick succession (i.e. rapid jumping). I thought that by loading it in once and rewinding it each time(with the mark and reset methods) the sound would stay in RAM but it doesn't seem to be doing that.I am open to any changes or a total rewrite. i just need it to work I've been stuck on audio for months.

```
package com.bigdirty1985.squaresthatmove.sound;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;

public class Sound {

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
private AudioStream audioStream;
private File file;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public Sound(File file) {
    this.file = file;

    try {
        this.audioStream = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream(this.file));
        this.audioStream.mark(100000000);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public void play() {


    AudioPlayer.player.stop(this.audioStream);



    AudioPlayer.player.start(this.audioStream);


    try {
        this.audioStream.reset();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public void stop() {
    AudioPlayer.player.stop(this.audioStream);
}
```

}

Comment: as an unrelated(ish) tip, make it async and it'll run faster

Comment: Yes, as Adam Ratzman suggested you can use a worker thread and run marking and rewinding there.

Comment: you can consider dropping this com.sun.... and start using javax.sound